# Ubuntu firewall how to configure idle connection timeout

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

How do I configure an idle connection timeout with Ubuntu firewall ?

I am encountering an issue in my production environment and suspect that the idle connection timeout in the  firewall is causing it. To prove it, I need to simulate this in my local environment.

I have two local Ubuntu machines. On one of them I turned on ufw, configured a certain port to be accessed and connected to it from the second machine. After waiting over an hour realized that one hour is not the default idle connection timeout.

Comment: What idle connection timeout? If you aren't doing NAT then there isn't one. For your _real_ problem in production, look at the device which is doing NAT in your network. This is where such a timeout would exist.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted a few things but was not able to reproduce this behaviour. The closest I came is to kill the connection using `tcpkill` or `ss`
Unless anyone has a better suggestion, I will mark this as an answer.